# Нужно динамически загружать значение в span

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть input, из которого нужно динамически (когда вводишь что-то в него) значение менялось в нужном span.
Желательно на чистом JS или Jquery

```js
const cartSumm = document.querySelector('.count');
const input = document.querySelector('input').val();
if (input > 0){
  cartSumm.text(input)
}
```

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
input{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="label">Введите количество товара:</span>
  <input></input>
<span>Количество товаров в корзине: <span class='count'>0</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const cartSumm = document.querySelector('.count');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', ({target}) => {     
   if ( target.value > 0){
      cartSumm.textContent = target.value;
    } 
});
```

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
input{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="label">Введите количество товара:</span>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <span>Количество товаров в корзине: <span class='count'>0</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь и такую оперативность!!!